# java decompilation

Tags: java, bytecode, decompiling

When decompiling a specific jar using java decompiler (http://java.decompiler.free.fr/) I got some strange code I cannot identify what is. can someone help me? the code is something like:

```
Foo.access$004(Foo.this);
```

or this

```
Bar.access$006(Bar.this);
```

or else

```
Baz.access$102(Baz.this, true)
```

What are these methods `access$004`, `access$006` and `access$102`?

Comment: A similar question was asked and got some good responses [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524358/what-is-this-referencing).

Comment: Do you want to use this decompiler, or is it an option to use JAD instead?
http://www.varaneckas.com/jad

Comment: You do not know why, Gergely? :) Jörn is right. JD does not Recognize all code patterns for synthetic methods.

Comment: Thanks guys. I was a heavy jad user, but I had switched to JD because jad does not decompile try/catch blocks properly. But now, I'm using both JD and jad to decompile java bytecode. :(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Synthetic methods like this get created to support acessing private methods of inner classes. Since inner classes were not part of the initial jvm version, the access modifiers could not really handle this case. The solution was to create additional package-visible methods that delegate to the private implementation.

```
public class Example {
    private static class Inner {
         private void innerMethod() { ... }
    }

    public void test() {
        Inner inner = ...
        inner.innerMethod():
    }
}
```

The compile would create a new method of the `Inner` class like this:

```
static void access$000(Inner inner) {
    inner.innerMethod();
}
```

And replace the call in the `test` method like this:

```
Inner.access$000(inner);
```

The static `access$000` is package visible and so accessible from the outer class, and being inside the same `Inner` class it can delegate to the private `innerMethod`.

Answer (score 2):

These are auto-generated methods which are created by the compiler in some cases (for example when accessing private fields of another class directly, e.g., in case of nested classes).

See also [What is the meaning of "static synthetic"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223268/what-is-the-meaning-of-static-synthetic) and [Synthetic Class in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399546/synthetic-class-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

If you get the relevant .class file (run jar through unzip), and run the .class file through [JAD](http://varaneckas.com/jad/)

```
JAD MyClass.class
```

then you may find that the output JAD file has decompiled that particular line in a more meaningful way, e.g.

```
Baz.access$102(Baz.this, true)
```

shows up in the JAD output as simply

```
myMemberVaiable = true
```

where myMemberVaiable is a member of class Baz that you will recognise.