# I have been editing this java file, and now i am left with one last error

Tags: java

So after many days of editing this java program, I'm new to java code, so i would be very greatful if someone could help me out here for the last error in the code. Basically the program spits out words/sentences at the push of buttons.
ERROR: "SpamBot.access$008();"
ERROR message: The method access$008() is undefined for the type SpamBot

If you need any more information just ask. Thanks in advance for any help

```
robot.keyPress(18);
      robot.keyPress(9);
      robot.keyRelease(18);
      SpamBot.access$008();
      if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(new JFrame(), "You have reviewed " + SpamBot.numreviews + " songs. Would you like to review another song?", "New song", 0) == 0)
      {
        SpamBot bot = new SpamBot(speed);
        dispose();
      }
      else
      {
        System.exit(0);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So are you sure that you have static method `access$008()` inside your `SpamBot` class?

Comment: Well, `SpamBot` doesn't have a method called `access$008`. Were you expecting it to have one?

Comment: Did you get the base code you are using by some Java decompiler?

Comment: Obviously the method `access$008()` at line 4 doesn't exist. (Also not sure where you got this code, but methods with dollar signs in them are not such a good idea)

Comment: So how would you guys fix this?

Comment: And once again im very new to this so as simple as possible would be very nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`access$008` is a synthetic method generated by the Java compiler in the outer class when a nested class accesses a private method from the outer class (or vice versa). The method itself does not exist in source code form. If you want to make the program run, you will need to call the "real" method that it represents.

Some details here:

- [What is the meaning of "static synthetic"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5223268/521799)
- [java decompilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379048/java-decompilation)

I suggest you use a better decompiler that can resolve these synthetic method accesses.

Comment: that makes a lot of scense as there were just so many errors in the code

Comment: which decompiler would you recommend i use jd-gui